# Google shopping API - pass ip address

Tags: api, google-shopping-api

In google shopping API there is a limitation as 2500 hits per day. So in order to cope up with this forum suggest to pass the ip address and it will act as 2500 per ip address per day. Hence how to pass that and will it be practical for a mobile device?

Regards,

Dilshan

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the userIp parameter along with your request.  See the docs here - https://code.google.com/apis/console-help/#PreventMonopolizing

However, I don't believe this allows 2500 requests per user ip address.  Rather it allows you to cap requests per second for a specific ip address, whilst the overall daily limit for the api key remains at 2500.